# How can I install Android NDK Cmake tools on headless server

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cmake, continuous-integration

I'm trying to configure an headless build-server to build an Android NDK project that's using Cmake to build the C++ part.

Right now I'm having this issue:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to find CMake.
  Install from Android Studio under File/Settings/Appearance & Behavior/System Settings/Android SDK/SDK Tools/CMake.
  Expected CMake executable at /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/cmake/bin/cmake.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a workaround!!

I've install **cmake** using this script: https://github.com/Commit451/android-cmake-installer

It's done the job until **Google** publish a fix so we can install it using the **Sdk Manager** ([here link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221907) of the issue

Comment: use this https://gist.github.com/ktnr74/8a927fbfe48cdc6f16b2#file-cron-daily-sdk-update instead - it automatically downloads the latest stable versions of the packages instead of relying on a 3rd party source to provide the exact versions

Comment: Thanks but no thanks, I prefer to know what I'm about to update and to test it before :)

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  It's crazy that Google hasn't provided a way to do this.

Comment: Totally, I think they will provide this possibility on the next few months.

Comment: @Ektos974, I never suggested to run it directly on the build servers - I run it on a test machine to populate our local repository cache

Answer (score 1):

Google has put a new tool into the SDK for this now (as of 25.2.3): [`sdkmanager`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html)

Answer (score 0):

The SDK manager can be used from the command line: http://tools.android.com/recent/updatingsdkfromcommand-line

One thing to note though is that that's actually a rather old version of the SDK manager and it's fed from a different set of data, i.e. the packages available in the standalone SDK manager will not necessarily match those in the Studio SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue myself.  AFAIK, the only way you can install the Android CMake is through Android Studio since the command line tools don't include CMake when you run: `android list sdk --all` (version r24.4.1)

As a workaround, you can just package the SDK with CMake and download them to your server until CMake becomes available via the Android CLI tools.